# IntentService getting location updates but unable to update map, throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am developing an app that required location updates even when the app is in background. I have set up `PendingIntent` which is received by `IntentService` class. I am getting updated location coordinates in `IntentService` class but when I try to update map using those coordinates,

**My app crashes and throws following exception:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye.Services.LocationHandler]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye.FragmentMaps.updateMap(FragmentMaps.java:159)
at com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye.Services.LocationHandler.onHandleIntent(LocationHandler.java:31)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

My `IntentService` class is as follows:

```
public class LocationHandler extends IntentService {

    FragmentMaps fragmentMaps = new FragmentMaps();

    public LocationHandler() {
        super(".Services.LocationHandler");
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {

            LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
            Location mLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();


            fragmentMaps.updateMap(mLocation);
            fragmentMaps.addressRequested();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            noti.setContentTitle("Fused Location");
            noti.setContentText(mLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLocation.getLongitude());
            noti.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationManager.notify(1234, noti.build());
            
        }
    }
}
```

**For Info**: Fragment Maps is the class where I have set up map and Implemented Google `LocationServices` API. In this class I have created two methods which I am accessing in my `IntentService` class.

**To Update Map and Marker:**

```
 public void updateMap(Location location) {

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        String timeStamp = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                .title("Me")
                .snippet(date + " " + timeStamp));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 17));
}
```

And other is:

```
public void addressRequested() {

            if (isAddressRequested){
                startIntentService();
            }
        }
```

**I am getting exception in following lines:**

> ```
> FragmentMaps.java:159  - `mMap.clear();`
>
> LocationHandler.java:31 - `fragmentMaps.updateMap(mLocation);`
> ```

I am unable to understand why this exception is occurring. Can anyone please help?????

Comment: `mMap` in `updateMap()` must be **NULL**.

Comment: `FragmentMaps fragmentMaps = new FragmentMaps();` this doesn't look good, you need to get a reference to the `FragmentMaps` that was created by the system instead of creating a new instance yourself.

Comment: how do I do that?? @Titus

Comment: How do I find out if it is null?? @jankigadhiya

Comment: That depends on what exactly you're trying to do, it is possible that there isn't any instance of `FragmentMaps` when the `LocationHandler` is started. If you're creating and starting the `IntentService` from your `FragmentMaps` fragment, you're better off using an `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: If I use `AsyncTask`, how will I create my `PendingIntent` object, as it has only three options: `getActivity()`, `getService()` and `getBroadCast()` ?? @Titus

Comment: `AsyncTask` are started using the `execute(...)` method, you won't be able to use a `PendingIntent` to start it, you will have to pass the data to the `AsyncTask` as parameter to its `execute(...)`  method or constructor.